# How to assign free space to only Ubuntu running machine?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, gparted

My problem is that I have an installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and there is not enough free space. My HDD has 3 parts: Ubuntu system(ext4), FREE SPACE(fat32) there I have all my big files and around 40GB which was originally windows. It is formatted now in `ext4` format and I want to add it to my Ubuntu installation how it is possible trough `gparted`?

[image: Gparted screenshot]

Comment: Does it have to `gparted` or are you comfortable using a terminal setting and something such as `fdisk`? It is a  rather easy setup.

Comment: If it will be safe I can take terminal version too...

Comment: Is the "free space"/40GB space empty, or does it currently have files on it?  Or are "free space" and 40GB separate partitions? If it's empty, doing what you ask is easy. Please edit your question to include a screenshot of gparted, and I'll take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I wouldn't have set up sda4 as fat32, but rather NTFS. You may decide to change this at a later time.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

The use of an extended partition (sda3) makes this a little difficult. I'll outline the easiest way first, and we can add more to the procedure if we have to.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- disable swap on sda5
- assuming that sda1 is empty, use `gparted` to delete sda1
- **resize** sda3 all the way to the left
- **move** sda6 all the way to the left
- **resize** sda6 all the way to the right
- click the Apply button
- reboot the computer

Comment: Nevermind.......

Answer (score -2):

As I perceive, you want to add a single drive to your system for more storage... If this is the case follow the below commands...

First, we will need to find the drive name in order to mount it... We can do this by running:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Next, you will have to find the drive's name relative to its size(Ex: `/dev/sda1`)...

Finally, you can simply mount this newly found drive by running:

```
mount drive_name_here location_here
```

#### What?

`drive_name_here` is basically the drive name you found while using `fdisk`

`location_here` is the location you want to mount the drive to... If you're not sure, I recommend mounting to `/mnt`...

#### Important

Now it is important to note that for you to be able to access this new storage instance you will have to store files to wherever you mounted to(Ex: `/mnt`)...

It is also important to note that you will have to re-mount this drive each time you reboot as it automatically unmounts when the machine is turned off... If you want this to be automatic, I recommend creating a startup script that does so...

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do it without remouting? I would like to add the sda1 part to sd6 part one time and have it like one part together.

Comment: I guess you could somehow delete the partition and then add the unallocated space to the drive you want... But this sounds riskier, then the above...

Comment: @NerdOfCode this doesn't answer the original problem... and it's incorrect/incomplete even if it did.